# Split a FASTA alignment file into all possible alignment pair in Python

Tags: python, sequence, biopython, fasta

I have an alignment FASTA file:

```
>SEQ1
AGGGGGCGGATAGGCAG-C--AGGCGCGGAGAGCGGCAGCG---GG---GGACG-AC-
AGGAACACCTATACTTcCTTCTAC-CAGACGAAC-------CGAGACa
>SEQ2
TGGGGGCGGATGGGCAG----AGGCGCGGAGAGCGGCAGCG-A-GG---GGACG-AC-
AGGAACATCTAHACCCcCTTCTAC-CAGACGAAC-------CGACACa
>SEQ3
TGGGGGCGGATGGGCAG-T--AGGCGCGGATAGCGGCAGCG-A-GG---GGACG-AC-
AGGAACATCTATACCCcCTTCTAC-CAGACGAAC-------CGACACa
>SEQ4
TGGGGGCGGATGGGCAG-A--AGGCGCGGTGAGCGGCAGCG-A-GG---GGACG-AC-
AGGAACATCTACACCCcCTTCTAC-CAGACGAAC-------CGACACa
>SEQ5
TGGGGGCGGATGGGCAG-G--AGGCGCGGAGAGCGGCAGCG-A-GG---GGACG-AC-
AGGAACATCTATACCCcCTTCTAC-CAGACGAAC-------CGACACa
```

and I would like to open this file, and create all the possible pair between SEQn

(without the same sequence in a pair)

for instance if there are 5 SEQ, then there will be `n(n-1)/2` 5(5-1)/2 = 10 groups
so

```
SEQ1 vs SEQ2
SEQ1 vs SEQ3
SEQ1 vs SEQ4
SEQ1 vs SEQ5
SEQ2 vs SEQ3
SEQ2 vs SEQ4
SEQ2 vs SEQ5
SEQ3 vs SEQ4
SEQ3 vs SEQ5
SEQ4 vs SEQ5
```

and I want to create 10 new FASTA alignment file:

**SEQ1 _vs_SEQ2.fa**

```
>SEQ1
AGGGGGCGGATAGGCAG-C--AGGCGCGGAGAGCGGCAGCG---GG---GGACG-AC-
AGGAACACCTATACTTcCTTCTAC-CAGACGAAC-------CGAGACa
>SEQ2
TGGGGGCGGATGGGCAG----AGGCGCGGAGAGCGGCAGCG-A-GG---GGACG-AC-
AGGAACATCTAHACCCcCTTCTAC-CAGACGAAC-------CGACACa

.
.
.
```

**SEQ4 _vs_SEQ5.fa**

```
>SEQ4
TGGGGGCGGATGGGCAG-A--AGGCGCGGTGAGCGGCAGCG-A-GG---GGACG-AC-
AGGAACATCTACACCCcCTTCTAC-CAGACGAAC-------CGACACa
>SEQ5
TGGGGGCGGATGGGCAG-G--AGGCGCGGAGAGCGGCAGCG-A-GG---GGACG-AC-
AGGAACATCTATACCCcCTTCTAC-CAGACGAAC-------CGACACa
```

Does someone have a fast idea (I have more then 122 taxa within each group which mean that I need to create 7381 files and 200 times)?

SO far I used:

```
records=SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse("mysequence.fasta", "fasta"))
list_taxa=list(records)
#Create all possible pairs 
List_pairs=[(list_taxa[i],list_taxa[j]) for i in range(len(list_taxa)) for j in range(i+1, len(list_taxa))]

count=0
SEQ_NAME="Name_seq"
for i in List_pairs:
  new_pair_name=i[0]+"_"+i[1]+"_"+SEQ_NAME
  output_file=open("/My_dir_where_to_create_the_files/"+new_pair_name+".fa","w")
  for a in i: 
    print(">",records[a].id,sep="",file=output_file)
    print(records[a].seq,file=output_file)
  print(int(count),"/",len(list(records)))
  count+=1
```

but it is not so efficient for the part where I create the pairs alignment files...

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to speed up. Probably the file writing takes most of the time. Is that your intention - to speed up the file writing?

Comment: yes exactly, I have around 1,476,200 files to write.

Comment: Do you have a toy fasta file so users can test their code performance against the current version? I think there are one or two things that could be optimized but in general, I would not expect too much performance enhancement. The file writing is the bottleneck, and this depends on your OS, not Python.

Comment: Have you considered that writing the pairs into millions of individual files is not the way to address whatever you try to achieve?

Comment: You could also look into something like [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) to parallelize your file writing in order to speed it up. I have to agree with Mr. T though, having millions of files is not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the files are in the same directory, this should be sufficient to have a list of all of the combos possible.

```
import os

ListofFiles = []
for file in os.path(WhateverYourDirectoryContainingTheFilesIs):
    if file.startswith('SEQ'):
        ListofFiles.append(file)
        
length = len(ListofFiles)
FileCombos = []

for i in range(length):
    for j in range(i+1, length):
        FileCombos.append(ListofFiles[i] + " vs " + ListofFiles[j])
```

From here, it shouldn't be too difficult to create your files as you need them, in your preferred method. I may come back to this tomorrow for a more pythonic solution, if no one else cooks one up before then.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to create a code but it is very long...